# Python tkinter disable "submit" button until all fields are populated

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am still relatively new at Python, but I am making a GUI app that has 2 entry fields and two filedialog buttons for the user to select the file to import and the directory to save the output of the program.  I am trying to do some validation on the entry fields to make sure that the user cannot click on the submit button until the entry fields are filled in and they have selected a file to import and a directory to save the output.

I got some of the way, but I'm stuck and I'm afraid I don't know enough about classes and methods to determine why I cannot change the status of my submit_button.config?

I have read various examples of how to do validation to entry fields including using validatecommand and building a validate method within my class.  I abandoned that because I could not figure out how to validate multiple fields within the submit_button command.

Here is my code as it sits right now.  I am struggling with the validate method within the Application class.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

class FileLogic:

    def __init__(self, path, save_location, request_id, exeuction_id):
        self.path = path
        self.save_location = save_location
        self.request_id = request_id
        self.execution_id = execution_id

    def fileopen(self=None):
        global fileName
        global path
        path = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select File", filetypes=( ("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("All files", "*.*") ) )
        fileName = os.path.split(path)[1]

        if not fileName:
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR - File Not Selected", "A file was not selected to process.  Please select a file by double-clicking or select file and press Open button")
        else:
            file_select_label = Label(root, text=("File Selected: " + fileName), width=75, bg="light blue")
            file_select_label.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)

        return path

    def filesave(self=None):
        global save_location
        save_location = fd.askdirectory(title = "Select Directory")

        if not save_location:
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR - Directory Not Selected", "This upload process will build an output file.  Please select a folder where the output file can be saved")
        else:
            file_select_label = Label(root, text=("Output file will be saved: " + save_location), width=75, bg="light blue")
            file_select_label.grid(row=8, columnspan=2)

        return save_location

    def submit(self, path, save_location, request_id, execution_id):

        print("FileLogic path: " + self.path)
        print("FileLogic save: " + self.save_location)
        print("FileLogic request: " + self.request_id)
        print("FileLogic execution: " + self.execution_id)
#        FileParsing.__init__(request_id)

class FileParsing:

    def __init__(self, request_id):
        self.request_id = request_id
#        self.execution_id_entry = execution_id_entry
        print("request id2: " + request_id)

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        global submit_button
        ##### Define the Labels ###############
        self.request_id_label = Label(root, text="Enter Rebate Request Id:", bg="light blue", bd=2, width=25).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.execution_id_label = Label(root, text="Enter Rebate Execution Id:", bg="light blue", bd=2, width=25).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.blank_label = Label(root, bg="light blue")
        ####### Define the Entry fields ##################


        self.request_id_entry = Entry(root,bg="light gray", bd=2, width=25, textvariable=request_id_entry).grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.execution_id_entry = Entry(root, bg="light gray", bd=2, width=25, textvariable=execution_id_entry).grid(row=1, column=1)

        ###### Define the Buttons ###############
        self.submit_button = Button(root, text="Submit", bg="gray", width=17, command= lambda: self.submit_click(path, save_location, request_id, execution_id))
        self.submit_button.config(state='disabled')

        self.open_file_button = Button(root, text="Select file to process", width = 30, command=FileLogic.fileopen).grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.save_location_button = Button(root, text="Select location to save output", width=30, command=FileLogic.filesave).grid(row=4, column=0)

        ##### Build the Grid ##################
        self.blank_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.blank_label.grid(row=5, columnspan=2)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=6, column=1)

    def validate(self, *args):
        print("validate")
        button_status = self.create_widgets(submit_button)

        if request_id_entry.get():
            print("normal")
            print(button_status)
#            self.submit_button.config(state='normal')
        else:
            print("diabled")
            print(submit_button.config)
#            self.submit_button.config(state='disabled')

    def num_check(self,var):
        var = self.var.get()
        print(var)
        if var.isnumeric():
            return True
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter Numeric Value")

    def submit_click(self, path, save_location, request_id, execution_id):
        self.request_id = request_id_entry.get()
        self.execution_id = execution_id_entry.get()

        a = FileLogic(path, save_location, request_id, execution_id)
        FileLogic.submit(a, path, save_location, request_id, execution_id)


root=Tk()

root.title("Rebate Bid Data Upload")
root.geometry("500x200")
root.configure(background="light blue")
request_id_entry = StringVar()
execution_id_entry = StringVar()

request_id_entry.trace("w", Application.validate)

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to get where the submit button is disabled until all the entry elements and filedialog attributes are complete.  Then for the entry fields I am checking to make sure they are numeric and I will want to make sure they are integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `textvariable` correctly. Also note that you are not keeping a reference of your `entry` widgets by defining them and calling the `grid` method on the same line.

```
def create_widgets(self):
    #global submit_button #you don't have to declare global here: submit_button is already an attribute

    ...

    self.request_var = StringVar() #create StringVars for request
    self.execution_var = StringVar() #ditto for execution
    self.request_id_entry = Entry(root,bg="light gray", bd=2, width=25,textvariable=self.request_var).grid(row=0, column=1) #set the textvariable to the StringVar
    self.execution_id_entry = Entry(root, bg="light gray", bd=2, width=25,textvariable=self.execution_var).grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.request_var.trace("w",self.validate) #trace changes on StringVar
    self.execution_var.trace("w",self.validate)

    ...

def validate(self, *args):
    if self.request_var.get() and self.execution_var.get(): #if both StringVars has content
        print("normal")
        self.submit_button.config(state='normal')
    else:
        print("disabled")
        self.submit_button.config(state='disabled')
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem.  I have a follow up that maybe you can help as well.  I would like to do the same thing to ensure that the user has selected a file before the submit_button if active.  Is there a way to do that?  Basically, I cannot figure out how I can check if the user has selected the "Open File" button and selected a file before I enable the submit_button